# Add to NSDictionary entries to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a for loop that goes through a series of dictionaries in an array.

How can I consolidate all the dictionaries entries as it goes through the for loop into one `NSMutableDictionary`?

I tried `addEntriesFromDictionary`, but its not working. Thanks for your help.

```
for (int i=0; i<sections.count; i++){

    formElements    = [[sections objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Dictionary"];        
}
```

Comment: What do you want to be the key? Maybe I missunderstand you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary * mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSDictionary * formElements in sections)
{
    [mutableDict addEntriesFromDictionary:formElements];
}
```

This should work if It's correct that they don't share any keys.

Answer (score 15):

you can add dictionary object like below.

```
NSMutableDictionary *mDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [mDict addEntriesFromDictionary:DictObj];
```

Comment: What is happening now is everytime I go through the loop, the last dictionary replaces the one before it rather than adding to it. So I have 5 entries in the first dictionary, and 2 entries in the second dictionary. Ultimately, I want to combine them to have a count of 7 entries.

Comment: @user984248 Yes because the keys replaces each other. You should probably use an array for this and just do [array addObject:formElements]

Comment: Can I do this and have a dictionary as the final result? I have all my code configured to read entries from a dictionary.

Comment: You can't have ONE dictionary. As I assume the dictionary in `sections` has the same keys you need a unique key for each dictionary or create a multidimensional dictionary.

Comment: The dictionaries in sections have different keys

Comment: @user984248 I updated my answer. addEntriesFromDictionary should work.

Comment: It works if you remove the loop and just use addEntriesFromDictionary. The accepted answer doesn't seem to work, but Pandey_Laxman's  answer does.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *mDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *mDict2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

//later suppose you have 5 object in mDict and 2 object in mDict2. combine in this Way.
    NSMutableArray *keys=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *obj=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    keys=[[mDict allKeys] mutableCopy];
    obj=[[mDict allValues] mutableCopy];

    [keys addObjectsFromArray:[mDict2 allKeys]];
    [obj addObjectsFromArray:[mDict2 allValues]];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:obj forKeys:keys];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate your dictionaries with -objectEnumerator or other methodfs of NSDictionary.

So inside your loop you enumerate your dictionary and add all objects an keys into one big dictionary.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Thats what I am looking for...one big dictionary at the end.

Comment: Yes, I can, however, Pandey_Laxman solution is better. I completely forgot this method. If you still want example I can provide one but I think problem is in duplicitous keys as MrAzulay said. My solution will no help you with this.

Comment: I understand. They have different keys tho. Let me see what I can do with an Array